# Prove the following proportions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried everything but to no avail. Please tell a way out.

> If $\dfrac a b = \dfrac b c = \dfrac c d$, then prove that $\dfrac {2a+3d} {3a-4d} = \dfrac {2a^3 + 3b^3} {3a^3 - 4b^3}$.

Comment: If you have in fact tried *everything* then you would have found out whether or not this is true.

Comment: Since you tried everything, I presume that includes cross multiplication. So, please give more details of what failed with you tried cross multiplication.

Comment: Two additional things about this forum. First, we do not know how to read minds, so please be precise in your formulations. Second, we do not call each other jerks.

Comment: No I haven't tried cross multiplication

Comment: The name-calling is inappropriate, but OP otherwise does have a point.  Nitpicking the use of language is unconstructive and can easily be interpreted as an attack, especially for a new user.  Obviously OP would've figured it out if OP literally tried *everything*, but it's clear that "I tried everything" means "I tried everything I could think of."  Also, re: cross multiplication, isn't it bad practice to establish an identity by playing with both sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Divide the top and bottom of the left side by $d$ to get
$$
\frac{2a + 3d}{3a - 4d} = \frac{2 \frac ad + 3}{3 \frac ad - 4}
$$
Now, note that
$$
\frac ad = \frac ab \cdot \frac bc \cdot \frac cd = \left(\frac ab \right)^3
$$
I'll leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{c}=\frac{c}{d}$

$\implies \frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{c}\implies  a=\frac{b^2}{c}\implies  a^3=(\frac{b^2}{c})^3=\frac{b^6}{c^3}=\frac{b^6}{bcd}=\frac{b^5}{cd}$

$\implies \frac{b}{c}=\frac{c}{d}\implies  c^2=bd \implies  c^3=bcd $

now $\frac{a}{b}\implies\frac{b}{c}=b^2=ac$
 \begin{aligned}
R.H.S    &=\frac{2a^3+3b^3}{3a^3-4b3}     \\
         &=\frac{2\frac{b^5}{cd}+3bcd}{3\frac{b^5}{cd}-4abc}     \\
         &=\frac{2b^5+3abc^2d}{3b^5-4abc^2d}      \\
         &=\frac{2a^2bc^2+3abc^2d}{3a^2bc^2-4abc^2d}     \\
         &=\frac{abc^2(2a+3d)}{abc^2(3a-4d)}     \\
         &=\frac{(2a+3d)}{(3a-4d)}     \\
&= L.H.S
  \end{aligned}
use $b^5=b^2b^2.b=a\times c\times a\times c\times b$